Set up and deployment of Apollo v3 + Aws Appsync + Vue 3 and Vite
I've been having a problem with a migration, I'm migrating from Vue 2 + Apollo v2 + @aws-appsync client to Vue 3 + vite + apollo v3.
Currently I have something like this
import AWSAppSyncClient from "aws-appsync";
import VueApollo from "vue-apollo";
import appSyncConfig from "@/assets/AppSync";

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient(
  {
    url: appSyncConfig.graphqlEndpoint,
    region: appSyncConfig.region,
    auth: {
      type: appSyncConfig.authenticationType,
      apiKey: appSyncConfig.apiKey
    }
  },
  {
    defaultOptions: {
      watchQuery: {
        fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network"
      }
    }
  }
);

const appsyncProvider = new VueApollo({
  defaultClient: client
});

window.App = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  provide: appsyncProvider.provide(),
  render: h => h(App),
});

this works while I am on a local environment, but when I try do deploy this app on aws I get an issue on using the @aws-appsync because when the build passes it has a require() statement resulting on this:

do you have any implementation or tips to overcome this error when deploying?
I'm trying to use @aws-sdk/client-appsync instead of the previuos library @aws-appsync because as far as I see this is only compatible with apollo v2 (github link here).
I've tried to use the client that the @aws-sdk/client-appsync has, following this (github link here) with no success.
I have also tried to change the vite config to see if it's possible to overcome that error with no success. github issue link
